# Database Design avoid redundancy

Tags: database, database-design

Database design is new to me, sorry for potential basic question.

The database I am designing is supposed to represent the following :

- My users can be either contractors or administrators
- contractors can issue withdrawals
- administrators can issue refunds (to refund withdrawals)
- a refund is linked to 1 or many (non cancelled) withdrawals
- a withdrawal is linked to 0 or 1 refund
- contractors can cancel withdrawals before they are linked to a refund

I therefore created 3 tables, ***USER*** ,***WITHDRAWAL*** and ***REFUND***.

As property of *WITHDRAWAL* records I created *status* , which represents if the concerned withdrawal is ( *pendingrefund* or *cancelled* or *refunded*).

Aiming to make a good database design, I would like to avoid redundancy and potential data missmatches.
Is creating that status property a good idea and why?

Indeed, one could deduce that withdrawal is refunded if it is linked to a refund (null or not).
On the other side, I should as well create a "isCancelled" field for withdrawal to know if it is cancelled. But that could lead to withdrawals being linked to refund while being cancelled (which is not possible)

Would you have any advice to help me making good design choices for this situation?

Comment: The Wikipedia article, [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), explains this and many other aspects of normalization.  There are many great books on the subject of database normalization.  Do the best you can and learn from the experience.

Comment: Follow an information modelling & DB design textbook presentation of some published design method & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question where 1st unsure/stuck. Right now you are just asking us to (re)write one with a bespoke tutorial. Google with 'site:stackoverflow.com' in researching before you consider asking. [ask]